# How to run hello.cpp and Jamfile located in boost/libs/python/example/tutorial directory?

Tags: c++, boost, bjam

I ran `bootstrap.bat` and also ran `bjam` from boost source directroy. However when I tried to run `bjam` from the above mentioned directory, I got the error message:

> 'bjam' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

I tried copying the `bjam` to the directory and tried running but I got:

> hello.cpp(7): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file:
>   'boost/python/module.hpp': No such file or directory

Where am I making mistake?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug of Boost.Python. Please report it to Boost.

The problem is that there is `Jamroot` file inside of `boost/libs/python/example` directory. Try renaming it to `Jamfile`.